# optimize the stored procedure with

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery, temp-tables

I want to optimize the below procedure by getting rid of the 3 times call to the same subquery. I thought I could make a temp table in a stored procedure and will update that, but don't know how to do that. any other ways to do this are welcome.

```
update some_table SET
status = (
case when 'OVERDUE' in (select status from other_table temp where Id = temp.Id)
then 'OVERDUE'
when 'UPCOMING' in (select status from other_table temp where Id = temp.Id)
then 'UPCOMING'
when 'PAID' in (select status from other_table temp where Id = temp.Id)
then 'PAID'
else 
null
END
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is more than one record in `other_table temp where Id = temp.Id` then You can use the following query:

```
update some_table SET status = 
  (select case when count(case when status = 'OVERDUE' then 1 end) > 0 then 'OVERDUE'
               when count(case when status = 'UPCOMING' then 1 end) > 0 then 'UPCOMING'
               when count(case when status = 'PAID' then 1 end) > 0 then 'PAID'
          end        
     from other_table temp where Id = temp.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest performing an update with left join:

```
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.status = t2.status
  FROM some_table t1
  LEFT JOIN other_table t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is

```
update s 
SET
    status = Case temp.Status  
                    when 'OVERDUE'  
                    then 'OVERDUE'
                    when 'UPCOMING'
                    then 'UPCOMING'
                    when 'PAID' 
                    then 'PAID'
                    else null
            END
FROM some_table S LEFT JOIN
other_table temp ON
s.Id = temp.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest phrase this as:

```
update some_table
    set status = (select top (1) ot.status
                  from other_table ot join
                       (values ('OVERDUE', 1), ('UPCOMING', 2), ('PAID', 3)
                       ) v(status, ord)
                       on ot.status = v.status
                  where ot.id = some_table.id
                  order by v.ord
                 );
```

I don't like repeating the specific `status` values.  This uses a `values` statement so they are included only once in the code.